# How to display both single quotes and double quotes in echo in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I need to display a string like *Today's "program"* as output in unix. But If i gave the below none of the options are working .

```
>echo "Today's "program""
Today's program

> echo "Today\'s "program""
Today\'s program

> echo 'Today's "program"'
>

echo 'Today\'s "program"'
>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to display double quotes inside double quotes, you have to escape them:

```
$> echo "today's \"program\""
today's "program"
```

You could also concatenate quoted strings:

```
$> echo 'today'"'"'s "program"'
today's "program"
```

Or just escape them all:

```
$> echo today\'s \"program\"
today's "program"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> echo 'Today'\''s "program"'
Today's "program"
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple possibilities:

```
> echo 'Today'"'"'s "program"'
Today's "program"
> echo Today"'"s '"program"'
Today's "program"
> echo Today\'s '"program"'
Today's "program"
> echo Today\'s \"program\"
Today's "program"
```

For the difference between these 3 kinds of escaping see for example [this article](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting).